# Value of KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar with ctrl key

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

On a `KeyPressEvent` I know how to detect when the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is down, but then I want to get <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+[what?].

With <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, `KeyChar` = 1, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> gives 2, etc. What is the best way to detect <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> input?

Here is my code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
    {
        Console.Write("(Ctrl) ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar)));
}
```

Entering <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> gives:

```
97
98
(Ctrl) 1
(Ctrl) 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion is to use [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event rather then KeyPress, because KeyPress works with processed input. KeyDown works with "raw" data (not quite, but enough for your purpose). KeyDown event handler has a parameter which holds data you need: [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, thanks. That works. KeyDown seems to have a few quirks of its own (the event fires repeatedly if you hold the ctrl key) but that is easy enough to work around. I'll do it that way.

Thanks for the reply.

Steven

Comment: You are welcome! You can see KeyUp event as well, maybe it will be more useful for you.